# Сделать клик на первой форме из второй формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы, мне нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку из второй формы в первой форме происходил performclick на toolStripMenuItem, но он не доступен

```
private void materialButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.toolStripMenuItem1.PerformClick();
        }


 private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p1.Text = "Player";
            p2.Text = "Computer";
        }
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. А так и задумано, что создаётся новый экземпляр? Если у вас уже открыта форма, то и кликайте по открытой форме. Может храните её в поле/свойстве... Вы создаёте новую корзинку с яблоками и что-то делаете в ней. Почему вы ждёте какой-то результат в другой корзинке? \n А вообще, может дополните ваш вопрос подробностями. Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы свернули с дорожки красивого кода в костыльные леса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте публичный метод в первой форме

```
public void ClickToolStrip()
{
    toolStripMenuItem1.PerformClick();
}
```

Открывайте вторую форму из первой так

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog(this); // или form2.Show(this);
```

Во второй форме

```
Form1 form1 = (Form1)Owner;
form1.ClickToolStrip();
```