# Почему переменная становится пустой (null)?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравстувуйте! Мне нужно взять переменную из другой формы, но когда я её беру, то она пустая. Как это исправить? Вот код первой формы:

```
public string input;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    input = textBox1.Text;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(input);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

А вот код второй формы, где переменная из первой формы становится пустой

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    string _input = form1.input;
    MessageBox.Show(_input);
}
```

Comment: Здесь точно таких же вопросов как и ответов на них десятка 2 с разными вариантами решений, странно что вы ничего не нашли. Хотя-бы вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1422323/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас переменная заполняется в событии клика по кнопке, а во второй форме этого не происходит. Передайте переменную в конструктор:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(input);
    form2.Show();
}
```

И примите ее:

```
public string input;
public Form2(string input)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.input = input;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(input);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!